# Template type restriction based on inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, game-engine

Say I have such *classes*:

```
class Scene {
public:
    Scene(void);
    ~Scene(void);
    virtual void update(void) = 0;
    virtual void construct(void) = 0;
    virtual void destroy(void) = 0;
};



class KillTheHedgehogScene : public Scene {

public:
    virtual void update(void) override;


    virtual void construct(void) override;
    virtual void destroy(void) override;

    EntitySceneGraph sceneGraph;
};
```

and I have a `SceneManager` class that goes something like this:

```
class SceneManager {
public:
    SceneManager(void);
    void loadNewScene(Scene* scene);

    Scene* getCurrentScene(void);
    void update(void);
private:
    Scene* _currentScene;
};
```

The way my code functions now, I would load a new scene by doing the following:

```
_sceneManager->loadNewScene(new KillTheHedgehogScene());
```

My issue with this is that whatever scope this is in has made the allocation, and now _sceneManager has to be in charge of it's deallocation. I want the `SceneManager` to handle both allocation and deallocation. I want to be able to call my `loadNewScene()` function in this way:

```
_sceneManager->loadNewScene<KillTheHedgehogScene>();
```

This way the scene manager can handle both the allocation and deallocation of the object, and gives it all control. My question however is how can I have **templates** restrict an input type based on **inheritance**. For example, I wouldn't want to be able to call:

```
_sceneManager->loadNewScene<SomeRandomOtherClass>();
```

`SomeRandomOtherClass` is not a child class of `Scene`. Is there a way to restrict the type?

Comment: Somewhere in `loadNewScene<T>`, you would have `_currentScene = new T` or similar. This would fail to compile if `T` is not in fact derived from `Scene`, so you would have this protection naturally. If you want a nicer error message, there's always `static_assert`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So I would be getting this functionality by default you say? I apologize for asking such an easily answered question then, I wish I could upvote an answer of yours ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a better error message when providing invalid template parameter, you may add `static_assert`, something like:

```
template <typename T>
void loadNewScene()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Scene, T>::value, "Type should inherit from class Scene");
    // Your implementation
}
```

Comment: Will this speed up compile times on fail as well, as the type is not checked implicitly against that entire scope, but rather explicitly against that first assert?